# functions.php and conditional tags

Tags: functions, conditional-tags

I'm having the following issue:
some conditional tags do not work on the functions.php file.

For example I'm trying to do the following:

```
if ( is_home() ) :
    wp_enqueue_script('accordeon_setup', '/wp-content/themes/44db/js/scripts-accordeon.js');
endif;
```

and although the site produces no error I cannot see the script in the home page.
The same thing happens with the following conditional tag:

```
if ( $post->post_parent == '12' ) :
```

Is there something I'm missing??
Both conditional tags run at the bottom of the functions.php

Thank you people !!!

Comment: the is_home part of the code is inside some function which is hooked to wp_enqueue_scripts action?

Answer (score 2):

`functions.php` is part of the loading process and way too early for conditional tags to work reliably. Any conditional logic should be hooked to and executed no earlier than `template_redirect` hook.

For scripts on front-end `wp_enqueue_scripts` is appropriate hook.

Comment: great, thanks for the prompt respond. So how do you do it? I want to load specific javascripts according to the page I'm in.

Comment: @ion [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) docs in Codex have plenty of examples of hooking. You only need to add conditional inside hooked function.

Comment: @Rarst Then where do you do that outside of `functions.php`?

Comment: @Little Big Bot you are confusing _where code is located_ and _when code is executed_. Code can (and usually plenty of it is) be located inside `functions.php`, but be hooked to execute at point different from when `functions.php` file itself is loaded. Basically this is difference between where function is defined and where it is called.